# Prove that $\frac{1}{x+1}$ is positive.

Tags: functions

Let $x>1$. I'm trying to prove that the function $y=\frac{1}{x+1}$ is positive. I've managed to prove that:

$$\frac{1}{x+1}=\frac{1}{x} + 1$$
$$\frac{1}{x} > 0$$
$$\frac{1}{x} + 1 > 1$$

However, how do I prove that $\frac{1}{x}>0$ is positive?

Comment: for $x\lt -1$, $y$ is negative. Do you mean to include $x\geq 0$ ?

Comment: Sorry, should have said that it needs to be positive over the interval (1, infinity). I'm effectively trying to prove that the function ln(x+1) is strictly increasing. Since it is defined on the interval (1, infinity), I need to prove that the function (1/(x+1)) is positive over the same interval.

Comment: $\frac{1}{x+1}\neq \frac{1}{x}+1$

Comment: Also, the function $\frac{1}{x+1}$ is only positive for $x>-1$, otherwise, it is negative. Look here https://www.desmos.com/calculator/u0dtmbm840

Comment: Yeah sorry I edited my comment above. I only need to prove that it is positive over the interval (1, infinity)

Comment: @M.Choy Learn how to MathJax to format your posts here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $y = \frac{1}{x + 1}$.

The numerator, $1$, is positive. The denominator, $x + 1$, is positive because it's said that $x > 1$, so $x + 1 > 1$.

Then $y$ is the quotient of two positive numbers, so $y$ must be positive.

Comment: Thanks! Beautiful solution

Answer (score 2):

For any $a\neq 0$ then $a\times \frac 1a=1>0$ thus $a$ and $\frac 1a$ have the same sign.

Thus $\frac 1{x+1}>0\iff x+1>0\iff x>-1$ and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

```
                 Answer:
```

*.     $X>1\Rightarrow X+1>2>0$

**.     Also $1>0$

Depending (*, **), we find$\frac{1}{X+1}>0 $